# Selecting value and joining tables in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables in SQL to do some analysis.

- SQL Table 1: *actions*
- SQL Table 2: *events*

I am trying to find out the last *event* before an *action* so I can determine which events are immediately preceding an action.

### My Tables

In the actions table I have rows containing

- Event_Time
- User_ID

In the events table I have rows containing

- Event_Time
- Event_Type
- User_ID

The actions don't happen at the same moment as the preceding event.

### My Query

I want to write a query which summarises the number of Users who took an action by the Event_Type which immediately preceded it.

For example if we had the following chronology for a single User_ID:

event > event > **event** > action > event

I would want to identify the Event_Type of the **event** in bold and count the user against it. Eg the output would be -

```
| Event_Type | Number of Users |
--------------------------------
| Some Event | 100             |
| Some other | 200             |
```

This was my first-stab at the query - but it doesn't work, I think maybe I'm not thinking about it in the right way.

```
SELECT COUNT(T_Actions.User_ID), T_Events.Event_Type
FROM T_Actions
LEFT JOIN T_Events ON T_Actions.User_ID=T_Events.User_Id
WHERE T_Events.Event_Time = 
  (SELECT T_Events.Event_Time 
  FROM T_Events
  WHERE T_Events.Event_Time < T_Actions.Event_Time 
  ORDER BY T_Events.Event_Time DESC
  LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY T_Events.Event_Type
;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle - 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/865e62/1/0

Many thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry - thanks for the heads up - I've added a SQLFiddle

Comment: Pretend we're human beings. And amend your data set accordingly.

Comment: @strawberry - i said the same thing to myself - but the timestamps will also sort correctly - so conversion to dates will just be extra work...

Comment: @Randy It's not difficult to provide user (i.e. us) - friendly data, and corresponding desired results.

Comment: The Event_Time is unix microseconds - I've converted the SQL Fiddle with the correct format.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/865e62/1/0

Comment: It looks like your query is working well, the user1 took action after the event type 3 and the user2 and user3 took action after the event type 1, so event type 1 has 2 actions and event type 3 has 1 action. What is the expected result?